# How to change the color of hyperlink if using <code> as the link's title

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have some hyperlinks with titles inside `<code>` `</code>`, such as:

```
<a href="http://some_link"> <code>Title</code> </a>
```

How can I change the color of the hyperlink when the mouse hovers on it? I first tried adding to the `.css` file

```
a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

but this doesn't do it, only the regular hyperlinks are colored. I then tried

```
a:hover, code:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

which almost works, but it also colors non-hyperlink `<code>` sections, such as

```
<code> some code here </code>
```

How can I color only the `<code>` hyperlinks, excluding the `<code>` non-hyperlinks, when the mouse hovers over them?

Comment: the default CSS color attribute for `code` is `inherit`, which would result in the code text appearing to be the same color as the link on hover.  You must have some overriding rule for code color.  Please provide that CSS as well as this is probably a specificity issue.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Here is the [.css](http://pastebin.com/c2xPzKuF). Dryden's answer does it for me though.

Comment: That's the problem.  `a code:hover` should be `a:hover code`.  The hover state belongs to the anchor.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I see, just starting with `.css/html`. Thanks!

Comment: @vsoftco You can read [**this**](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to understand CSS Specificity, consult [**this**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/) every time you need a CSS reference, and check [**this**](https://github.com/bendc/frontend-guidelines) for Frontend Guidelines. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz Thanks, will keep it handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the real issue is a specificity issue because of a rule giving `code` a specified color, I can recommend two approaches.  The first is that you can specify a color for the rule `a code`.

```css
code{color:red;}
a:hover, a:hover code{color:green}
```

```html
<a href="http://some_link"> <code>Title</code> </a>
```

The other is to allow `code` to inherit its color if it's in an anchor tag.

```css
code{color:red;}
a code{color:inherit}
a:hover{color:green}
```

```html
<a href="http://some_link"> <code>Title</code> </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify anchor tags inside of the `<code>` blocks like so:

```
a:hover, a code:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/gcbvduyb/

```
a:hover, a:hover code {
  color: red;
}
```

Would also work.

Answer (score 0):

```
a:link {
  color: blue;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**Please check this link:-http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/links-mouseover.shtml**

Comment: I knew how to change the link colors. This was about changing links that had their title inside `<code>` `</code>` tags.